# Configurar o IP para acesso ao servidor utilizando Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma aplicação Java que utiliza o Hibernate, para desenvolvimento fiz a configuração do banco de dados utilizando o localhost porém para uso em outros computadores eu vou precisar definir o IP que irá possuir o banco de dados(Servidor) no meu projeto utilizo o arquivo Persistence.xml

Pensei por meio de uma tela inicial, o usuário registrar o IP da máquina em um arquivo de configuração criado na instalação.

Mas agora me deparo com a situação de ter que informar para o Persistence qual o IP informado no arquivo criado pelo processo de instalação.

Segue abaixo o exemplo do meu Persistence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence                                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ConexaoPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>br.com.exemplo.modelo.Exemplovenda</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conexao?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: não entendi a pergunta, você fez o banco no localhost e quer adicionar a um servidor externo?

Comment: para desenvolvimento eu criei um banco local, até na configuração utilizei o localhost, mas para produção eu preciso informa de forma externa qual é o IP do meu servidor.

Comment: Você tentou substituir o localhost pelo teu ip com o banco? Por exemplo //meuip.com:porta/nomedoBD ?

Comment: sim, e funciona sem problemas, só que não sei se no cliente ele vai manter o mesmo ip que eu fixei na programação, neste caso fico muito amarrado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem a pergunta eu passei uma situação parecida tempos atrás. No caso a solução que usei foi a seguinte:

- Criar um mapa com as propriedades diferentes das do arquivo `persistence.xml`, no seu caso, o IP do banco de dados; e
- Passa esse mapa para a função `createEntityManagerFactory()` que vai utilizar as propriedades do arquivo `persistence.xml` e vai substituir apenas aquelas que você definiu no mapa.

**Exemplo:**

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "uma URL informado pelo usuário"); //Essa propriedade vai substituir aquela que está no arquivo.

EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ConexaoPU",mapa);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Claro que se o usuário digitou apenas o IP você vai ter que tratar a URL, por exemplo:

```
String ip = "192.168.0.0:3306"; //Algum IP e porta informado pelo usuário
String url = "jdbc:mysql:" + ip + "/caminho para arquivo";
```

Answer (score 3):

### Primeira Opção

Você pode passar durante a criação do `EntityManagerFactory` um arquivo de propriedades obtido em seu classpath como exemplo abaixo:

```java
Properties p = new Properties();

p.load(new FileInputStream("um/caminho/no/seu/classpath/persistence.properties"));

// ajuste detalhes que não deseja expor no arquivo de propriedades.

EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unitAppName", p);
```

Caso precise informar os dados de autenticação você pode criptografar o arquivo e descriptografa-lo internamente após carrega-lo e antes de usa-lo.

### Segunda Opção

Caso você não esteja informando quais entidades em seu arquivo `persistence.xml`, você pode criar um arquivo novo com os parâmetros personalizados conforme sua instalação, este arquivo deve estar no classpath de sua aplicação, além disso caso venha precisar de maior proteção, você pode proteger este arquivo em um arquivo Jar criptografado, porém precisará registrar um classloader especializado para descriptografa-lo.